# Force files creation in a folder to have a fixed group:user

Tags: linux, apache, file-permissions

I'm on linux.

It is possible to force a folder to have a fixed couple of user:group for new files created ?

The issue is that every time a file is created by the use www-data it is the not accessible to my main user.

I have added `MYUSER` to `www-data` group and `www-data` to `MYUSER` group, however this is not enough.

I would like that all files under my /www/ folder were created with `MYUSER:WWW-DATA` couple regardless if it created by me or by apache.

is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use acl to do that 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists

it will not always create the files as another user then the user who created the file, but you have control of which users have default permissions to the files